# How to move checkbox of terms and conditions up [odoo 13]

Tags: checkbox, odoo, odoo-13

does anyone know how to move the conditions and positions checkbox up? I found the code for this checkbox in odoo[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWlsu.jpg) and it has this parameter, but when I change the state of this parameter to "before", nothing happens
odoo version 13.0, ecommerce module

code of checkbox

```
<template id="payment_sale_note" inherit_id="payment" name="Accept Terms &amp; Conditions" customize_show="True" active="True">
    <xpath expr="//div[@id='payment_method'][hasclass('js_payment')]" position="before">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox float-right mt-2 oe_accept_cgv_button">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_cgv" class="custom-control-input"/>
            <label for="checkbox_cgv" class="custom-control-label">
                I agree to the <a target="_BLANK" href="/shop/terms">terms &amp; conditions</a>
            </label>
        </div>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my odoo v13, i have managed it like that :

```xml
<template id="my_payment_tokens_list" inherit_id="payment.payment_tokens_list" >
   <xpath expr="//form[hasclass('o_payment_form')]/div[1]" position="before">
     <div class="pl-4 mb-3">
       <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_cgv" class="custom-control-input" required="This field is required"/>
       <label for="checkbox_cgv" class="custom-control-label"> I agree with <a target="_BLANK" href="/shop/terms"><u>General Terms and Conditions of Sale</u></a></label>
    </div>    
   </xpath>
</template>
```